# Can you sacrifice a tapped creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a creature has both a sacrifice and tap ability can you tap it for the tap benefit and then sacrifice it for the sacrifice ability?

(Example: [Gemhide Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gemhide%20Sliver) taps for mana, [Basal Sliver](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Basal%20Sliver) gives mana on sacrifice. So can I tap then sacrifice a sliver?

Comment: The answer received so far are correct, but if you are thinking about one *specific* creature please state which it is, because you might be missing something.

Comment: Slivers: Gemhide gives mana on tap, Baal sliver gives mana on sacrifice. So can I tap then sacc?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As a general answer: Whenever you are asked by a spell or ability for a certain target, or when you have to pay certain costs, then as long as the chosen object has all the required properties, all other properties can be whatever they are.

So if an ability requires you to "sacrifice a creature", it doesn't say anything about the creature being tapped or untapped, so as long as it's a creature, you can sacc it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, yes, you can use the abilities of tapped creatures that do not have tapping the creature as part of the cost to use the ability even when the creature is tapped.